# How to compare and select particular object from list using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq

I've two set of list of objects. One named as SellWish and another as holdingAdviceDecisions. These two objects are linked via two items such as:
SellWishId and
HoldingAdviceId

I'm trying to get the matched values between these with the following condition

```
 holdingAdvice.CustomerDecision == CustomerDecision.FollowsAdvice
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
var item = sellWishes.Where(sellWish =>
 holdingAdviceDecisions.Where
 (holdingAdvice => sellWish.Id == holdingAdvice.TradeInstructionId
      && holdingAdvice.CustomerDecision == CustomerDecision.FollowsAdvice));
```

But I'm getting following errors:

1. Error   CS1662
   Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate
   return type

2.Error CS0029
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<HoldingsAdvice.Contracts.HoldingAdviceDecision>' to 'bool'

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `where` needs a delegate that returns a bool, ` holdingAdviceDecisions.Where` returns an IEnumerable

Comment: so you want entries from sellWish where there is at least one holdingAdviceDecision that matches?

Comment: yes, I need the set of SellWish which matches the condition above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need

```
var items = sellWishes.Where(sellWish =>
  holdingAdviceDecisions.Any
    (holdingAdvice => sellWish.Id == holdingAdvice.TradeInstructionId
   && holdingAdvice.CustomerDecision == CustomerDecision.FollowsAdvice));
```

note that this reurns all matching entries, if you know you only the first (or null)

```
 var item = sellWishes.Where(sellWish =>
        holdingAdviceDecisions.Any
  (holdingAdvice => sellWish.Id == holdingAdvice.TradeInstructionId
    && holdingAdvice.CustomerDecision == CustomerDecision.FollowsAdvice)).FirstOrDefault();
```